# Double loop for each column per row in matlab

Tags: matlab, for-loop

The following code does what it should and works of one column.

```
%% Working loop


z = HongKongPrices(1:end,114);

 zeros = false(size(z));

 r = size(z,1);
 c = size(z,2);


for i = 5:r
    if z(i) == z(i-4) && z(i) == z(i-3)
        zeros(i-3:i) = 1 
    end
end

z(zeros) = NaN
```

I am trying to execute the for-loop on a per column basis for HongKongPrices, however the following code fails (I am starting with three columns for time reasons).

```
 %% Non workling loop

 z = HongKongPrices(1:end,[80 85 115]);

 zeros = false(size(z));

 r = size(z,1);
 c = size(z,2);

 for k = 1:c
      x = z(1:end,k)
    for i = 5:r
        if x(i) == x(i-4) && x(i) == x(i-3)
            zeros(i-3:i) = 1 
        end
    end
 end

x(zeros) = NaN
```

Comment: What's wrong with the code? With a random 200x200 matrix it runs without any exception and as you did not describe the intended behaviour it's impossible to tell what you want.

Comment: Use column indexing there - `zeros(i-3:i,k) = 1` and at the end, change the  z values with `z(zeros) =  NaN`. As a good practice, use some other variable name than `zeros`, which is a built-in MATLAB function.

Comment: @Daniel that's strange, it appeared to me that I did describe the intended behavior with the help of a code that is working for a single column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the variable `x` at all. You can use logical indexing in you `if` statement. Instead of `x(i)`, use `x(i,k)` and so on. Of course you have to do the same with `zeros`.

```
z = HongKongPrices(1:end,[80 85 115]);

zeros = false(size(z));
r = size(z,1);
c = size(z,2);

for k = 1:c
    for i = 5:r
        if z(i,k) == z(i-4,k) && z(i,k) == z(i-3,k);
            zeros(i-3:i,k) = 1 
        end
    end
end

z(zeros) = NaN;
```

PS: `zeros` is a Matlab function, so it would be better to use another variable name. Like this you won't be able to use the `zeros` function in your code.

Comment: It does what it should, thanks! Is there any way to speed up the process as it appears to take forever?

Comment: @Frank What's the datasize for `z`?

Comment: @Divakar 479x1672. And thats just the smaller one.

Comment: @Frank What about the biggest one, so that we mustn't run into out-of-memory problems with any prospective solution.

Comment: @Divakar the biggest one is yet to be determined but will be something around 479x12000. If it is of any help: 16 GB 1333 MHz DDR3 with 3.2 GHz Intel i5

Comment: @Frank Also, since the speeding up process might need a good overhaul of the existing solution, I think a new question would suit it better asking for performance/ vectorization and if you decide to go that way, you may link that to this question saying its a follow up question?