# How to speed up a double loop in matlab

Tags: performance, matlab, for-loop, matrix, vectorization

**This is a follow-up question of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28124718/double-loop-for-each-column-per-row-in-matlab).**

The following code takes an enormous amount of time to loop through. Do you have any recommendations for speeding up the process? The variable `z` has a size of 479x1672 and others will be around 479x12000.

```
z = HongKongPrices;

 zmat = false(size(z));

 r = size(z,1);
 c = size(z,2);

 for k = 1:c
    for i = 5:r
        if z(i,k) == z(i-4,k) && z(i,k) == z(i-3,k) && z(i,k) == z(end,k)
            zmat(i-3:i,k) = 1 
        end
    end
 end

z(zmat) = NaN
```

I am currently running this with MatLab R2014b on an iMac with 3.2 Intel i5 and 16 GB DDR3.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use **[`logical indexing`](http://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/vectorization.html#btjk576-1)** here to your advantage to replace the `IF-conditional` statement and have a small-loop -

```
%// Get size parameters
[r,c] = size(z);

%// Get logical mask with ones for each column at places that satisfy the condition
%// mentioned as the IF conditional statement in the problem code
mask = z(1:r-4,:) == z(5:r,:) & z(2:r-3,:) == z(5:r,:) & ...
                                            bsxfun(@eq,z(end,:),z(5:r,:));

%// Use logical indexing to map entire z array and set mask elements as NaNs
for k = 1:4
    z([false(k,c) ; mask ; false(4-k,c)]) = NaN;
end
```

---

### Benchmarking

```
%// Size parameters
nrows = 479;
ncols = 12000;
max_num = 10;
num_iter = 10; %// number of iterations to run each approach, 
               %// so that runtimes are over 1 sec mark

z_org = randi(max_num,nrows,ncols); %// random input data of specified size  
disp('---------------------------------  With proposed approach')
tic
for iter = 1:num_iter    

    z = z_org;
    [..... code from the proposed approach ...]

end
toc, clear z k mask r c

disp('---------------------------------  With original approach')
tic
for iter = 1:num_iter

    z = z_org;
    [..... code from the problem ...]

end
toc
```

### Results

**Case # 1: `z` as `479 x 1672`** (`num_iter = 50`)

```
---------------------------------  With proposed approach
Elapsed time is 1.285337 seconds.
---------------------------------  With original approach
Elapsed time is 2.008256 seconds.
```

**Case # 2: `z` as `479 x 12000`**  (`num_iter = 10`)

```
---------------------------------  With proposed approach
Elapsed time is 1.941858 seconds.
---------------------------------  With original approach
Elapsed time is 2.897006 seconds.
```

Comment: thats fantastic! I was not aware of logical indexing and will read about this right now. Meanwhile, could you add the last condition, i.e. `z(i,k) == z(end,k)` so I can mark this question as solved? Thanks again.

Comment: @Frank Could you check how this performs for your datasize? Runtimes?

Comment: marvelous! Thank you again for your time and consideration.